# Error file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\storage\app\): failed to open stream: No such file or directory usando laravel excel

Tags: laravel, excel, laravel-excel

estoy tratando de insertar unos datos desde una archivo excel... Hice el enlace simbolico a la carpeta Storage, hice config:cache, pero aun asi me da el error:  **file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\storage\app): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Tengo esta funcion en mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    //iniciamos guardando el archivo en alguna direccion de tu proyecto
    $archivo = $request->file('serie');
    /* $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $nombre_original = $timestamp. '-' .$archivo->getClientOriginalName(); */
    $r1 = Storage::disk('local')->put($archivo,'archivo');
    //hasta aqui el guardado

    try {

        DB::beginTransaction();

        $serializacion = new Serializacion();
        $serializacion->fecha_serializacion = $request->get('fecha_serializacion');
        $serializacion->status = $request->get('status');
        $serializacion->usuario_id = $request->get('usuario_id');
        $serializacion->ingreso_material_id = $request->get('ingreso_material_id');
        $serializacion->det_ingreso_material_id = $request->get('det_ingreso_material_id');
        $serializacion->save();

        $material_id = $request->get('material_id');

        //ahora lo recuperamos para poder trabajar en el
        $ruta = storage_path('local') ."/". $archivo;
        if($r1) {
            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta, function($hoja){
                foreach($hoja->get() as $index => $fila){
                    DB::table('det_serializacions')->insert([
                        'mac'=>$fila->mac,
                        'serie'=>$fila->serie
                    ]);
                    $serializacion_id = $fila->serializacion->id;
                    $material_id = $fila->material_id;
                    $fecha_serializacion = $fila->fecha_serializacion;
                  $fila->save();
                }
            });
        }//cierre if


    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;
    }


    }
```

Se supone que deberia cargarse y almacenarse el archivo, para luego recorrerlo y ademas de las filas propias del excel, añadir unas filas adicionales.

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿En qué parte de tu código usas `file_put_contents`? No lo veo por ningún lado. La pregunta además es confusa, ¿intentas escribir en un Excel que ya existe o el Excel se crea en ese mismo contexto? Es que pareces decir que primero lo creas, luego lo guardas y luego lo abres para escribir más cosas. Si el archivo debe crearse en ese contexto, ¿no es mejor recoger toda la información que tendría el archivo y crearlo directamente, sin tener que manipularlo posteriormente?

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, segun el codigo que esta en la funcion este deberira: cargar desde un formulario y se guarda en el storage, luego se deberia recorrer cada fila para hacer el insert

Comment: Bien, eso es lo que debería hacer, pero aquí hablamos de un error cuyo código no aparece en la pregunta. Significa que hay un problema básico de depuración de código. Te aconsejo que pierdas un poco de tiempo aprendiendo a depurar, porque ganarás horas... meses más adelante. **¿Dónde se estaría llamando a `file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\storage\app)`?** Siguiendo la lógica de tu programa deberías encontrarlo, es más, deberías saberlo, si entiendes tu código. A veces un código llama a otro, y ese código puede tener error, es lo que parece que aquí ocurre precisamente.

Comment: Parece un problema de permisos en el directorio `storage`. No sé como se hace en windows, pero asegurate que el server tenga permisos de escritura ahí.